# How to use bind_rows() to merge datasets while keeping the names of the datasets as a variable

Tags: r, dplyr, purrr

I have a few datasets that I'm merging together with bind_rows. My code looks like this

```
df1 <- data.frame(v1 = 1:10, v2 = 11:20)
df2 <- data.frame(v1 = 11:20, v2 = 1:10)

list(df1, df2) %>%
  bind_rows(.id = "name")
```

I want the `name` column to read `"df1"` for `df1` and `"df2"` for `df2`. I know I can use `set_names()` to do this manually...

```
list(df1, df2) %>%
  set_names(c("df1", "df2")) %>%
  bind_rows(.id = "name")
```

...but I want a way to do this programatically that works no matter what the dataset names are. How can I do this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

We can use `dplyr::lst` or `purrr::lst` which would automatically return a named `list` with the arguments

```
library(dplyr)
dplyr::lst(df1, df2) %>%
  bind_rows(.id = "name")
#   name v1 v2
#1   df1  1 11
#2   df1  2 12
#3   df1  3 13
#4   df1  4 14
#5   df1  5 15
#6   df1  6 16
#7   df1  7 17
#8   df1  8 18
#9   df1  9 19
#10  df1 10 20
#11  df2 11  1
#12  df2 12  2
#13  df2 13  3
#14  df2 14  4
#15  df2 15  5
#16  df2 16  6
#17  df2 17  7
#18  df2 18  8
#19  df2 19  9
#20  df2 20 10
```

Comment: Wow, and it's super fast to boot! I'm going to wait a bit to pick this answer because I seem to remember another way to do it and I want to see if someone else chimes in, but this is good.